# Margin-left not working in IE8 in DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo, margin

I'm using dojo 1.8 and I'm trying to set a Margin left to a div node but it's not rendering it in IE8.

Here's what I have:

```
dojo.create("div", {"class": "something", style: "margin-left:100px;"}, this.something);
```

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Did you firebug or use some other developer tool to see how the css is getting interpeted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dojo.create()` is [deprecated in Dojo 1.8](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/create.html). You should use [dojo/dom-construct::create()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-construct.html#id19) instead.

You also need to make your `style` attribute an object:

```
domConstruct.create("div", { style: { "margin-left": "100px" }, "class": "something" }, this.something);
```

Another approach would be to delegate applying your styles and class(es) to `dom-style` and `dom-class`, respectively:

```
var myNode = domConstruct.create("div", null, this.something);
domStyle.set(myNode, "margin-left", "100px");
domClass.add(myNode, "something");
```